# How do I mock netconf session in unit tests Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, session, netconf

I am using juniper's netconf package ("github.com/Juniper/go-netconf/netconf") to establish a netconf session in my code.

I wanted to know how can I mock a netconf session in my unit tests.

My methods are:

```
func TestMyFunction(t *testing.T) {
    getSSHConnection = mockGetSSHConnection
    got := MyFunction()
    want := 123
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, want) {
        t.Errorf("Error expectation not met, want %v, got %v", want, got)
    }
}
```

```
func mockGetSSHConnection() (*netconf.Session, error) {
    var sess netconf.Session
    sess.SessionID = 123
    return &sess, nil
}
```

The problem arises when MyFunction() has a line that defers sess.Close() and it's throwing error due to nil pointer dereference

```
func MyFunction() int {
    sess, err := getSSHConnection() // returns (*netconf.Session, error)
    if err == nil && sess != nil {
        defer sess.Close() -> Problem happens here
        // Calls RPC here and rest of the code here
        
    } 
    return 0
}
```

So, what changes can I make on mockGetSSHConnection() method so that sess.Close() won't throw error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nil` pointer error originates within [the `Close` function](https://github.com/Juniper/go-netconf/blob/81d90f4028b7bdcbaeae42a0df9a7419fa9c3664/netconf/session.go#L28) when `Close` is called on the underlying `Transport`. Fortunately `Transport` is an `interface` type that you can easily mock and use in an actual instance of the `netconf.Session`. For example like so:

```
type MockTransport struct{}

func (t *MockTransport) Send([]byte) error {
    return nil
}

func (t *MockTransport) Receive() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte{}, nil
}

func (t *MockTransport) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (t *MockTransport) ReceiveHello() (*netconf.HelloMessage, error) {
    return &netconf.HelloMessage{SessionID: 123}, nil
}

func (t *MockTransport) SendHello(*netconf.HelloMessage) error {
    return nil
}

func (t *MockTransport) SetVersion(version string) {
}

func mockGetSSHConnection() (*netconf.Session, error) {
    t := MockTransport{}
    sess := netconf.NewSession(&t)
    return sess, nil
}
```

Note that the function you want to test currently return `0` and not the `SessionID` of the session. So you should fix that before the test is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OOP and "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock" package

for example create

```
type SshClientMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (s *SshClientMock) GetSSHConnection() {
    return //what do you need
}
```

in your unit test:

```
sshClient := SshClientMock
sshClient.On("GetSSHConnection").Return(what do you need)
```

and then call your method